# Life and death in Latin

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

I want to use "Life and death" in Latin as a title for an important writting, but I want to make sure its translation and context is correct:

Is this the correct way?:
**Vitam et Mortem**

Comment: You have put them both in the accusative case when nothing (appears) to be happening to them. Is there some context here? "Life &  death" of whom or what? The nominatives are "vita" & "mors", if that's any help.

Comment: @tony Life and death in general context, like saying "I'm been thinking in life and death" not my life or death... just as a thought.

Comment: If you are thinking about....Then "concerning", in Latin: "de" + ablative case; giving "de vita et morte" = "concerning life & death". Further, "I am thinking" = "cogito" (Pock.Ox.Lat. Dict. gives: consider, ponder, meditate; look forward to; imagine) alternatively, "puto" = think, imagine, believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is kind of a subjective question. Here's what I can think of:

Vita et Mors (or Mors et Vita) -- I like this for its simplicity, readability, and recognizability.

Vita Morsque (Or Mors Vitaque) -- It means the same thing "Life and Death" but it is more idiomatic Latin, I think.

Res Vitae et Mortis -- "Res" means "matters, goings-on." This means "Matters of Life and Death"

De Vita et Morte -- Means "On/about life and death."

Vivendum et Moriendum -- Means "Living and Dying." This might be a good choice, as the Romans were quite fond of noun-ized verbs.

Per Vivendum, Per Moriendum -- Means "By living, By dying." This would give a sense of how you got your information. This would be good if your narrator is a ghost or omniscient in some way.

Vivere et Mori -- Means "To live and to die." This is probably the best translation of what you're looking for. Thank you to Cerebus for this suggestion.

Comment: Good suggestions! I'm a bit less certain about your gerunds, though. As subject or direct object, the infinitive is used, rather than the gerund, so *vivere et mori*.

Comment: Good point. The infinitives are a bit more general like Sxntk was wanting. I'll add those to my list.

Comment: I do think the per + gerunds work as I mentioned. But, without prepositions, you're right that the standalone gerunds would be strange.

Comment: Yes, I meant the lonely ones. I seem to remember *preposition + -ndum* is generally analysed as gerundive rather than gerund, though I forgot why.

Comment: I will use for simplicity Vita et Mors, thank you very much for your suggestion!